# hibernate one-to-one query error after insert data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I use the `hibernate` `one-to-one` mapping to build the relationship between `Stock` and `Category`. The data of `Category` table is imported when my web app start use the following `sql` statement.

```
insert into Category (name, created_time) values ('top', now()), ('recommend', now()), ('editor choice', now()), ('random', now());
```

At first, I can get the category list by execute `CategoryDAOImpl.getCategories`, but after execute `CategoryDAOImpl.getCategorybyName(String name)`, the method `CategoryDAOImpl.getCategories` won't work, the output message show the hibernate sql execute without return.

Is there a wrong when I implemented `one-to-one` mapping?

How can I solve this question?

**Stock.java**

```
@Entity
public class Stock {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Category category;

    @Column(name = "created_time")
    private Date date;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public long getId() {
       return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the category
     */
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    /**
     * @param category the category to set
     */
    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    /**
     * @return the date
     */
    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    /**
     * @param date the date to set
     */
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

}
```

**Category.java**

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "created_time")
private Date date;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "category")
private Stock stock;

/**
 * @return the id
 */
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the date
 */
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

/**
 * @param date the date to set
 */
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}

/**
 * @return the stock
 */
public Stock getStock() {
    return stock;
}

/**
 * @param stock the stock to set
 */
public void setStock(Stock stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}

}
```

**CategoryDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see com.example.mywebapp.dao.CategoryDAO#getCategories()
 */
@Override
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Category.class).list();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see
 * com.example.mywebapp.dao.CategoryDAO#getCategorybyName(java.lang.String)
 */
@Override
public Category getCategorybyName(String name) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Category> categories = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Category.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("name", name)).list();
    if (categories != null && categories.size() > 0) {
        return categories.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * @return the sessionFactory
 */
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

/**
 * @param sessionFactory
 *            the sessionFactory to set
 */
public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

}
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the debug output of hibernate, I figured out what causes the issue. When query from `Category`, hibernate will join the table with `Stock` because there is a `one-to-one` mapping relationship between them, so the result is not correct. By setting projections and corresponding result transformer on `Category` query, it works fine.

```
@Override
public List<Category> getCategories() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("id"), "id");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("name"), "name");
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("date"), "date");
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
            .createCriteria(Category.class).setProjection(projectionList)
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Category.class))
            .list();
}
```